# Get (background) color of HTML page of some top element

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, `document.body.style.backgroundColor` does not return the right color in my case (it isn't even set), because the page is all filled with divs.

**Is there some way to get the color of some pixels in the top pixel row?** Or some other generic way to get some background color of some top (or dominating) element? The solution doesn't have to be exact, only mostly working (esp for my cases :)).

One method, which kinda works ok for my current case, is this:

```
$("div").css("background-color")
```

However, I'm not fully happy with it, as it makes too much exceptions, like it needs JQuery, and expects that this returns a related div, and that div has a background color set.

Comment: Can you write your requirement precisely? cuz right now its too messy, ain't sure what you really need.

Comment: So you don't know which element in page has background color set?

Comment: @Mr.Alien: The question in bold, basically. That is as precise as possible. Other solutions which don't get me that color are approximations, but also ok, if it's not possible otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should find the first child element of the body with a background color.
Note that it does not search for nested elements.

```
var el = document.querySelector('body > *'), color = null;

while ( el && !color) {
    color = el && el.style ? el.style.backgroundColor : null;
    el = el.nextSibling;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y99ML/)

Comment: That doesn't work for my case because the color is set via a CSS class.

Comment: Then you have to somehow use `getComputedStyle`, but that returns the default color `rgba(0,0,0,0)` (transparent) even for elements without a background color set, so it's going to be hard to get working.